# simple algorithm to fill remaining fields with last value

Tags: perl

I've got a line separated by commas which I need to split into 4 separate variables.

i.e. a line like `val1, val2, val3, val4` would result in the following 4 variables:

```
var1 = val1
var2 = val2
var3 = val3
var4 = val4
```

Now I can easily get this by using something like this:

```
($var1, $var2, $var3, $var4) = (split /,/, $inputLine);
```

However, if the inputline contains less than 4 values, the remaining variables should contain the last available value.

I.e. if the inputline is `val1, val2`, then the variables should be set like this:

```
var1 = val1
var2 = val2
var3 = val2
var4 = val2
```

What would be an elegant way to approach this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`//=` is the ["defined or" operator](http://www.effectiveperlprogramming.com/2010/10/set-default-values-with-the-defined-or-operator/).

```
$var2 //= $var1;
$var3 //= $var2;
$var4 //= $var3;
```

As said in the linked post, if you use a version prior to `5.10`, the equivalent is :

```
$var2 = defined($var2) ? $var2 : $var1;
$var3 = defined($var3) ? $var3 : $var2;
$var4 = defined($var4) ? $var4 : $var3;
```

---

Some strings are falsey values :

```
$str = '';
if ($str) {
    print "true\n";
} else {
    print "false\n";
}
# prints 'false'

$str = '0';
if ($str) {
    print "true\n";
} else {
    print "false\n";
}
# prints 'false'
```

If `''` or `'0'` are "invalid" values in your porgram, you can use the `||=` operator.
If only `undef` shoud be overwritten, use one of the two versions above.

```
$var2 ||= $var1; # $var2 will be overriden if $var2 is undef or '' or '0'
$var3 ||= $var2; # $var3 will be overriden if $var3 is undef or '' or '0'
$var4 ||= $var3; # $var4 will be overriden if $var4 is undef or '' or '0'
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, unfortunately this doesn't seem to be working with the version of perl I'm running here: `Can't modify division (/) in division (/)`

Comment: I changed `//=` with `||=` and it seems to be working now

Comment: `//` is for newer versions of perl. `5.14+` if I recall correctly. `||` works almost the same - it just handles empty string `''` and `0` differently.

Comment: Changing `//=` to `||=` will not work if 0 or '' are valid values in your data.

Comment: @Sobrique It's 5.10+.

Answer (score 1):

It takes a preparatory step and an extra variable and then it's a one-line loop.

```
# my (@in, $tmp) = ($var1, $var2, $var3, $var4); # If it was split
my (@in, $tmp) = (split /,/, $inputLine);

for ($var1, $var2, $var3, $var4) {
    $tmp = $_ = shift @in || $tmp;
}
```

The bad: `$tmp` stays around.

---

**Update**  As explained in [LeGEC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/86072/legec) solution, in order to keep the data that evaluates to false but may be legitimate in the application (`''` and `0`) the loop-line above should be changed to

With v5.10 or later

```
$tmp = $_ = shift @in // $tmp
```

For earlier versions

```
$tmp = $_ = (@in ? shift @in : $tmp)
```

If data surely cannot be `''` or `0`, or if these indeed need be replaced, only then may `||` stay.

Comment: Thanks, nice solution as well